# How can I inject a custom angular service without mocking it into a test in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

My modules and tests are declared as shown below, but when I try to inject ContentBlocksService into beforeEach(mock.inject((ContentBlocksService)...   it says Unknown provider ContentBlocksServiceProvider... any ideas?

Modules:

```
module projName.ContentBlocks {
 "use strict";

 console.log("contentBlocks.module: start");

 angular.module("projName.contentBlocks", [
   "ui.router",
   "ui.bootstrap",
   "ui.bootstrap.tpls",
   "textAngular",
   "as.sortable",

 // shared modules
   "projName.filters"
 ])

  .service("ContentBlocksService", ContentBlocksService)
  // etc

}
```

Tests:

```
module projName.ContentBlocks {
  "use strict";

  describe("ContentBlocksDetailPageService", () => {

  beforeEach(mock.inject((_$http_, _$log_, _$q_, _$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_) => {
    log = _$log_;
    httpMock = _$httpBackend_;
    alertService = new Shared.AlertService(_$q_, _$log_);
    $q = _$q_;
    $http = _$http_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  /// etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
beforeEach(mock.module('projName.contentBlocks'));
```

is required before `beforeEach(mock.inject(...))` in order for the module to be loaded in specs.

Comment: my other problem now is 'failed to instantiate ui.bootstrap' due to either not available or misspelled.. tried adding ui.bootstrap to the karma file to no avail, any ideas?

Comment: It indicates that ui.bootstrap file was not loaded. Any way, it is better to free the module from dependencies that are not required for its units to be tested. The dependencies should be loaded in parent module then.